# How can I perform a segue from a scene to a normal view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am developing a game on Xcode. In one of these scenes of the storyboard, I created a game. I tried to make a segue from this scene to another view controller but an error doesn't stop showing up "Thread 1: Fatal error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I have tried to delete the segue and create it again and tried to change that code for this one: `self.view!.window!.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "salir", sender: self)`

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion
import AudioToolbox
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var viewController: GameViewController!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    for touch in touches {
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        for nodeITapped in self.nodes(at: pointOfTouch) {

            if nodeITapped.name == "button" {


              self.viewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "salir", sender: self)



                return
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

I expect this segue to actually work.

Comment: Have you set the wanted next view controller identifier as 'salir'?

Comment: yeah i've already done that

Comment: You have to click on the segue on storyboard and set the identifier THERE as salir. Also, is the "viewController" property on GameScene set? Maybe that's triggering the error.